# Installing pyaudio on windows and getting this error

Tags: python, windows

After installing pyaudio on windows I get this error:

```
   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: 'c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import 
    sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-02do7ejp\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-02do7ejp\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-yfv9cuts\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
             cwd: C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-02do7ejp\pyaudio\
        Complete output (17 lines):
        running install
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
        copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
        running build_ext
        building '_portaudio' extension
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -Ic:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj       
        _portaudiomodule.c
        c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
        src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
        src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
        error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
        ----------------------------------------

  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-02do7ejp\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-02do7ejp\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, 
    '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-yfv9cuts\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Has anyone faced a similar problem? If so, please let me now how you solved it.

Comment: This is the important piece of your log: `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory`

Comment: Did you try finding the missing file? Then installing it if it's not there?